# Fortumo service not working in sandbox mode

Tags: sms, fortumo

I made Fortumo service and started to test it (in sandbox mode).

In "Edit" tab I entered
"To which URL will your payment req be forwarded to?": http://mywebsite.com/sms

When I go to "Test" tab and trying to test my service I don't get any HTTP GET request on this url (http://mywebsite.com/sms) from your service.

I expected to receive HTTP GET request from your server with data about transaction. Why I not received that request?

Answer (score 0):

Please contact Fortumo support at support@fortumo.com for the quickest reply on any technical issue. Your account ID at Fortumo & backend notification URL (assuming it's not actually http://mywebsite.com/sms) would be needed to check the logs.

Most commonly, the issue would be a timeout on your server side (request timeout is 30 sec), a certificate issue or a request processing error.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue, First of all need to know either it works with sending the GET request to defined URL in Service dashboard.
if it works then there would be a problem with our code , if it doesn't work with sandbox mode, then there is only one way to make it live and then test.

Here is my code I am using for testing and inserting some records into db just to test if fortumo touch this page or not .

```
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO wpcf_terms (name, slug)
VALUES ('John', 'john@example.com')";


if(isset($_GET['credit_name'])) {

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }


}
$conn->close();
```